# Integrating Modified Bessel Function of Second Kind

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I am trying to show that
$$
\int t(K_s(t))^2dt = \frac{1}{2}t^2(K_s(t))^2-\frac{1}{2}t^2K_{s-1}(t)K_{s+1}(t).
$$
It is taken from this link https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/21/01/04/01/01/01/0004/. I am not even sure that this is correct. I tried integration by parts to get
\begin{align*}
\int t(K_s(t))^2dt &= \frac{1}{2}t^2(K_s(t))^2-\frac{1}{2}\int t^2\cdot 2K_s(t)\cdot \frac{-1}{2}(K_{s-1}(t)+K_{s+1}(t))dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}t^2(K_s(t))^2 +\frac{1}{2}\int t^2K_s(t)(K_{s-1}(t)+K_{s+1}(t))dt.
\end{align*}
I am stuck here and still figuring out how to proceed.

Comment: One approach will be to differentiate the right-hand side to show that it reduces to the integrand, but this does not seem especially satisfying. Mathematica does verify the identity is correct, however.